# how to get data from react-meteor-data container only when it's ready?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I am having trouble getting data from my container since isReady stays false. When looking in MeteorToys the collection does get loaded so I do not understand why.

On the server I define the StaticContents collection which gets loaded with "api" data. (which I typed in myself for now)

```
export const StaticContents = new Mongo.Collection("staticContents");

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish("polled-publication", function() {
    const publishedKeys = {};
    const poll = () => {
      // Let's assume the data comes back as an array of JSON documents, with an _id field, for simplicity
      const data = [{ _id: 1, name: "jef" }, { _id: 2, name: "jan" }];
      const COLLECTION_NAME = "staticContents";
      data.forEach(doc => {
        if (publishedKeys[doc._id]) {
          this.changed(COLLECTION_NAME, doc._id, doc);
        } else {
          publishedKeys[doc._id] = true;
          this.added(COLLECTION_NAME, doc._id, doc);
        }
      });
    };
    poll();
    this.ready();
  });
}
```

On the client I import this StaticContents collection and react-meteor-data and put this in a container which passes these variables to my react component.

```
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor";
import { Mongo } from "meteor/mongo";
import { StaticContents } from "../api/gap.js";
import { createContainer } from "meteor/react-meteor-data";
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Dashboard extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log("log the props");
    console.log(this.props);
  }
  render() {
    //const gapData = Session.get("gapData");
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="starter-template">
          <h1>This is the dashboard page.</h1>
          <p className="lead">
            Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br />{" "}
            All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.
          </p>
          <p>
            {this.props.testprop}
            <br />
            {this.props.isReady && this.props.content.name}
            <br />
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default createContainer(props => {
  // Do all your reactive data access in this method.
  // Note that this subscription will get cleaned up when your component is unmounted
  const handle = Meteor.subscribe("polled-publication");

  return {
    isReady: handle.ready(),
    content: StaticContents.find({}).fetch(),
    testprop: "this is a testprop"
  };
}, Dashboard);
```

When logging the props isReady is false and content is an empty array.
How should I solve this and why is it taking so long to load?

I am using the official meteor guide "loading from rest" as a guide.
https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#loading-from-rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are logging `this.props` in **componentWillMount**, it will get executed once - before *<Dashboard>* get mounted and probably before the *polled-publication* subscription is ready. During which, *isReady* and *contents* would be what you are getting. Subsequently, the subscription should get ready and the props would become what you expect.

You can put the `console.log` within **render** to check out the values of the props on each render.

Also in

```
{this.props.isReady && this.props.content.name}
```

*this.props.content* is an array, so it doesn't make much sense to reference a *name* field.

Comment: You are the best! I did not know you can console.log in render. Either way now it's clear.